# Subtracting php arrays

Tags: php, arrays, count, compare

I can seem to solve this problem.
I have two lists of visitors/country that come from sql

> us,us,uk,fr,uk,uk,uk

and

> us,uk

I made arrays out of them with `array_count_values()`:

```
Array ( [us] => 2 [uk] => 4 [fr] => 1 )
Array ( [us] => 1 [uk] => 1)
```

Now, I would like to get the first minus the second

```
Array ( [us] => 1 [uk] => 3 [fr] => 1 )
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Cant believe how many users dont read the question carefully...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
foreach($arr1 as $key => &$val){
    if(isset($arr2[$key])){
        $val -= $arr2[$key];
    }
}
```

Comment: Please use descriptive variable names so your code is easier to understand.

Comment: `$arr` and `$val` are descriptive enough. This loop could easily be plugged into a function which takes two arrays as params and doesn't want to describe their context.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
foreach($bigArray as $country => $count)
{
  if(isset($smallArray[$country]))
  {
    $bigArray[$country] -= $smallArray[$country];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work if there are values in the second array that are not in the first:

```
$array1 = array("us" => 2, "uk" => 4, "fr" => 1);
$array2 = array("us" => 1, "uk" => 1, "ca" => 1);

$keys = array_keys(array_merge($array1, $array2));
foreach ($keys as $key) {
    $result[$key] = (isset($array1[$key]) ? $array1[$key] : 0) - (isset($array2[$key]) ? $array2[$key] : 0);
}
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [us] => 1
    [uk] => 3
    [fr] => 1
    [ca] => -1
)
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<?php
$array1 = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,a,b,c,d);
$array2 = array(a,b,c,d);
$result = array_diff($array1, $array2);
print_r($result);
?>
```

Comment: How is this going to subtract the values for the same keys?

Comment: -1 cause it does not do what he needs... And neither does array_diff_assoc

Comment: @AlienWebguy probably for a good reason, because it doesn't work.

Answer (score -3):

This helps

```
$result = array_intersect($array1, $array2);
```

Comment: He wants to subtrackt the values for the same keys, this is not going to help him